# Does $\Bbb Z[X]$ determine $X$?

Tags: topological-groups

For a Hausdorff space $X$, consider the free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ generated by $X$. Equip it with the finest topology which makes the map $X\to\mathbb{Z}[X]$, $x\mapsto [x]$ continuous and turns $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ into a topological group.

My question is whether this topological group determines $X$.
So if $Y$ is another Hausdorff space such that $\mathbb{Z}[X]\cong\mathbb{Z}[Y]$ as topological groups, does it follow that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: I feel the need to point out that by (an easier version of) the [Dold-Thom theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dold%E2%80%93Thom_theorem), $\mathbb Z[X]$ is additively homotopy equivalent to $\prod_n B^n H_n(X; \mathbb Z)$. Since spaces are not determined by their homotopy groups, the analogous question "does the additive homotopy type of $\mathbb Z[X]$ determine the homotopy type of $X$" has a _negative_ answer.

Comment: $\mathbb Z[X]$ reads more like $\mathbb Z$ with elements of $X$ freely adjoined than a free abelian group generated just by $X$.

Comment: You might find the following paper useful since it gives a way to find countable examples in the non-abelian case, that is, for free topological groups: Jan Baars, Equivalence of certain free topological groups, Commentationes Math. Univ. Carolinae, 33 (1992), no. 1, 125-130. For instance, $F(\omega+1)\cong F(2\omega+1)$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is no.

If $X$ is a simplicial set then $\mathbb Z[|X|]\cong|\mathbb Z[X]|$. That is, your topological abelian group freely generated by the realization of $X$ is homeomorphic to the realization of the simplicial abelian group $\mathbb Z[X]$ freely generated by $X$. By the Dold-Kan Theorem a simplicial abelian group is determined up to isomorphism by its normalized chain complex. This chain complex for $\mathbb Z[X]$ is isomorphic to the cellular chain complex of the CW complex $|X|$.

Therefore we have a counterexample if we have two simplicial sets, or simplicial complexes, $X$ and $Y$ such that $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are not homeomorphic but such that their cellular chain complexes are isomorphic. It is easy to find examples. For example, you can take $X$ to be a $1$-dimensional simplicial complex having five vertices and four edges that looks like the letter "X" and take $Y$ to be a $1$-dimensional simplicial complex having five vertices and four edges that looks like the letter "Y".

Comment: Very cute! Forgive me for the ignorant question, but is the normalized chain complex really *isomorphic* to the cellular chain complex, not just homotopy equivalent?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Yes. In each case a basis is given by the nondegenerate simplices.

Answer (score 4):

As folks have correctly pointed out, my previous positive answer was not right. (And I have deleted it.)  And Simon Henry observes that one can't even recover a finite set $S$ from $\mathbb Z[S]$ in a functorial way, suggesting strongly that the answer to the question is no.

Comment: How are you recovering the multiplication on $C(X)$? A priori you only get the vector space structure. You could get the multiplication if you knew the comultiplication $x \mapsto x \otimes x$ on $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ but that isn't assumed here.

Comment: Yes, I'm affraid that answer is wrong. Group homomorphism don't form a ring. You need to know the generators to get the ring structure. For e.g. that approach would give a functorial reconstruction of X, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: (For S a finite set you can reconstruct S form Z[S], but not in a functorial way)

Comment: Perhaps it is best to simply delete the answer?